# st_intersects works without error message but got empty list

Tags: r

I have two datasets.

One is a CSV file, which has a listing of Airbnb in New York.
Is from that website: http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data
And NY Zipcodes from that website: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Business/Zip-Code-Boundaries/i8iw-xf4u/data?no_mobile=true

```
ny <- read.csv("NY/listings.csv")
zc <-  st_read("ZIP_CODE_040114/ZIP_CODE_040114.shp")
```

Now I would like to find out which listings lie on which zipcodes.

```
nysf <- st_as_sf(ny, coords=32:31, crs="epsg:2263")
zc <- st_transform(zc,crs="epsg:2263")
```

When I am doing this code below both have the same crs system, so [st_intersects](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_binary_pred.html) should work, but when I gave the code, I got an empty list.

```
st_intersects(nysf,zc)
```

I don't understand, why I got an empty list as output, because the code should be right? I want an output which gives which listings are in which zipcodes. So it should be which id listings are in which zipcode

I am expecting an output like this

| zipcode | id |
| --- | --- |

Could it be that both have to be shapefiles for it to work?
Do I have to choose point in polygon to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Columns 32 and 31 are latitude and longitude. They are **not** EPSG 2263. So this:

```
nysf <- st_as_sf(ny, coords=32:31, crs="epsg:2263")
```

is going to tell `sf` the wrong thing. You need to first construct an `sf` data frame in the **correct** coordinate system (lat-long, epsg:4326 probably) and then `st_transform` it to the other one.

Create `sf` saying the coordinate numbers are lat-long numbers:

```
> nysf = st_as_sf(ny, coords=32:31, crs="EPSG:4326")
```

Transform the underlying coordinate numbers to the same coordinate system as `zc` (note I get the CRS from `zc` so I can be sure its correct):

```
> nysft = st_transform(nysf, st_crs(zc))
```

Then I can do the `intersects`:

```
> inters = st_intersects(nysft,zc)
```

This returns a list of the same length that `nysft` has rows, so for each row you can see which polygons that point intersects (with overlapping polygons, you can get more than one intersection):

```
> inters[[1]]
[1] 5
> inters[[2]]
[1] 79
```

You do get some multiples, for example point number 1505 intersects two polygons:

```
> inters[[1505]]
[1] 105 221
```

which intersects those two polygons because they seem to be nested:

```
> d = inters[[1505]]
> plot(zc[d, ]$geometry, col="red")
> plot(zc[d, ]$geometry, col="#80808080")
> plot(nysft[1505, ]$geometry, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

But anyway, set the CRS correctly for your data, then transform to the matching one to do spatial operations.